# Capture Mouse Event: left pointer down + Mouse Leave

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a board game.
I have a component square where the clients click.

The player can click on a square 3 different ways, that triggers 3 different actions: left click, right click and double click.

My problem occurs when the player press down the left click on a square, but keeps moving and releases the cursor on another square. Then nothing happens, which is normal.

Do you know how to capture that event ?

Edit: here is the code:

```
class Square extends PureComponent {

    render() {

        return (
            <button
                onLeftClick={() => doAction1()}
                onContextMenu={(ev) => {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    doAction2();
                }}
                onDoubleClick={() => doAction3()}
            >
                btn test
            </button>
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G done